# Django view return value with AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am working with Django and AJAX,

I have a template where people can select an option and then click a submit button. The button fires an Ajax function that sends the data to my view where it is processed and should return a value back to the template.

The issue is when the post goes through, it hits the view, and nothing is returned to the template, I am not sure if this is because the view isn't getting any data, but it isn't firing any of my conditional statements, so it acts like its working but doesn't return anything.

My HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" id="buy_form" name="buy_form" action="{% url 'manage:buy' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="buy_top_section">
        <div class="width">
            <div class="spacing">
                <h3 class="sell_title">How much do you want to sell?</h3>
                <input type="text" id="amount" class="buy_input_top" maxlength="10" name="amount" type="number" required>
                <select id="selected" class="buy_selection" name="wanted">
                    <option value="generate_b">BTC</option>
                    <option value="generate_e">ETH</option>
                    <option value="generate_l">LTC</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <span class="float_clear"></span>
            <button id='generate' type="submit" value="currency_details" class="custom_button"l">Generate
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- What needs to be returned from thew view -->
<h1>{{ address }}</h1>
```

My AJAX
    $(document).on('submit', '#buy_form', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/manage/buy/',
        data:{
            currency:$('selected').val(),
            amount:$('#amount').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: function (){

            }
        })
    });
```

My Django View

```
def buy_corsair(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

    if request.POST.get('wanted') == 'generate_b':
        # Get the amount entered
        amount = request.POST.get('amount')
        # Generate a new B address
        new_b_address = client.create_address(b_account_id)['address']
        # Point the address at the user
        request.user.user_address.b_address = new_b_address
        # Save address to current user
        request.user.user_address.save()
        # Pass the address to the template
        context = {'address': new_b_address}
        return render(request, context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Buy Page
    path('buy/', views.buy_corsair, name='buy'),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax requests run in background, django render function render a template to body, so you can not render this way. You could like this;

dont forget include

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def buy_corsair(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        if request.POST.get('wanted') == 'generate_b':
            # Get the amount entered
            amount = request.POST.get('amount')
            # Generate a new B address
            new_b_address = client.create_address(b_account_id)['address']
            # Point the address at the user
            request.user.user_address.b_address = new_b_address
            # Save address to current user
            request.user.user_address.save()
            # Pass the address to the template
            return HttpResponse(new_b_address)
```

in your js;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'/manage/buy/',
    data:{
        currency:$('selected').val(),
        amount:$('#amount').val(),
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
        },
        success: function (data){
            $('h1').html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the way it was processed, thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score -1):

in your Django view

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
def buy_corsair(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      if request.POST.get('wanted') == 'generate_b':
         # Get the amount entered
         amount = request.POST.get('amount')
         # Generate a new B address
         new_b_address = client.create_address(b_account_id)['address']
         # Point the address at the user
         request.user.user_address.b_address = new_b_address
         # Save address to current user
         request.user.user_address.save()
         # Pass the address to the template
         context = {'address': new_b_address}
         return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context))
```

in your js

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'/manage/buy/',
    data:{
        currency:$('selected').val(),
        amount:$('#amount').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success: function (response){
            console.log(response);
            //access the value and print it in console//
            var obj=JSON.parse(response)["address"];

            alert(obj);
      
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Try to add more info to explain how OP can fix the problem. Code is a great way to do it, but also make sure to explain your answer!